# toggling class on click by javascript on ajax post success

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This code works fine for first click as it changes class along with image which is referenced from CSS. But when I click second time it acts like clicked in previous class which I assume removed already.

```
 if(Model.SeenItWantToSeeIt.Status==1)
              {
                    <div class="movie_data">
                    <div  class="usermovie_option"><a href="javascript:Void(0)"   class="dont_want_to_see_it" title="I have seen this movie">&nbsp;</a></div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

              }
              else{
                    <div class="movie_data">
                    <div  class="usermovie_option"><a href="javascript:Void(0)"   class="want_to_see_it" title="I have seen this movie">&nbsp;</a></div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

              }
```

And Javascript for toggling class is

```
 $(".want_to_see_it").click(function () {
        var wantToSeeIt = $(this);
        alert('clicked on want to see it.');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SeenIt", "MovieProfile")',
            data: { Status: 1, MovieID: movieID },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                wantToSeeIt.removeClass();
                wantToSeeIt.addClass("dont_want_to_see_it");
                $("dont_want_to_see_it").show();

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error occurred.');
            }

        });

    });

    $(".dont_want_to_see_it").click(function () {
        alert('clicked on donot want to see it');
        var wantToSeeIt = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SeenIt", "MovieProfile")',
            data: { Status: 0, MovieID: movieID },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {

                wantToSeeIt.removeClass();
                wantToSeeIt.addClass("want_to_see_it");
                $("want_to_see_it").show();

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error occurred.');
            }

        });

    });
```

And problem is it shows "clicked on donot want to see it" or "clicked on want to see it" as alert every time I click . What I have to do is this message should alternate every time I Click on their respective image.

Comment: You want the same element to use different clickevent alternatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that you want to change the handlers dynamically on click of each element. But events are bound to the element directly using click event.

1. One option is to hide and show respective items.
2. Another option is to bind and unbind events.
3. Third option is to use event delegation. Your requirement will work with this since with event delegation events are not directly attached to the elements, they are instead delegated. So the moment you swap the class name event subscribed for that class name will automatically get delegated. SO next click on the same element will go to the other event handler attached its new `class name`. See if this is what you were looking for.

   ```
    $(document).on('click',".want_to_see_it" ,function (e) {
      var wantToSeeIt = $(this);
       alert('clicked on want to see it.');
       ///Your ajax
       wantToSeeIt.removeClass();
       wantToSeeIt.addClass("dont_want_to_see_it");
       $(".dont_want_to_see_it").show();
     });

      $(document).on('click',".dont_want_to_see_it" ,function (e) {
       alert('clicked on donot want to see it');
       var wantToSeeIt = $(this);
       ///Your ajax
       wantToSeeIt.removeClass();
       wantToSeeIt.addClass("want_to_see_it");
       $(".want_to_see_it").show();

   });
   ```

Note:- In the example i have attached to the document, You should n't attach it to the document, instead attach it to any containing element that is present in DOM at any time.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KfzdR/)

*There was another issue, you missed `.` before the classname in your ajax success.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to `unbind("click")` to clear the previous handler then bind a new event handler for its new class.

Instead of unbinding and rebinding, do in one handler:

```
$(".usermovie_option a").on("click", function () {
    var status = 0;
    if ($(this).hasClass("want_to_see_it")) {
        status = 1;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SeenIt", "MovieProfile")',
        data: { Status: status, MovieID: movieID,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {                
            $(this).toggleClass("want_to_see_it");
            $(this).toggleClass("dont_want_to_see_it");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Error occurred.');
        }

    });

});
```